# VMware Power CLI: how to get custom attributes for a datastore

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter, powercli

I am trying to get a custom attribute value for my datastore, but bumping into an issue with type incompatibility. Is there anything I am doing wrong below, and how to fix it?

```
PowerCLI C:\> $ds = Get-Datastore -Name YK
PowerCLI C:\> $ds

Name                               FreeSpaceGB      CapacityGB
----                               -----------      ----------
YK                                  14,528.467      14,901.750


PowerCLI C:\> Get-Annotation -Entity $ds -CustomAttribute ykcustattr_global
Get-Annotation : Cannot bind parameter 'Entity'. Cannot convert the "YK" value of type "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.DatastoreManagement.VmfsDatastoreImpl" to type "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.Inventory.InventoryItem".
At line:1 char:24
+ Get-Annotation -Entity $ds -CustomAttribute ykcustattr_global
+                        ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Annotation], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetAnnotation
```

**Note 1**: I am able to get a custom attribute for a virtual machine, cluster and host. The problem is with the Datastore only.

**Note 2**: I guess the problem is that Get-Datastore returns *Datastore object*, while Get-Annotation expects *InventoryItem object* for -Entity. It is not clear if it is possible to do a cast/transformation or anything like that.

**VMware vCenter version: 6.5**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on the VMware forum and decided to post it here. Briefly, the problem exists, but there is a workaround:

https://communities.vmware.com/message/2826274#2826274